# linuxmint lmde: How to find out Debian release?

Tags: mariadb, linux-mint, debian-based

I have a linuxmint lmde installation and I would like to install MariaDB, a data base system like MySQL. To do this [MariaDB](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=1000Mbps&distro=Debian&distro_release=squeeze) asks me which release I have. How can I found out which debian release my linuxmint lmde installation has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the current way of doing this is running `lsb_release -r`. Also you could do a `cat /etc/debian_version` which is storing the release on a Debian system.

Comment: @frian Thanks for answer. I got "Release 1". I suppose that this referres to linuxmint lmde distribution and not to Debian. MariaDB Homepage list the following options: Debian "sid", Debian 7 "Wheezy" and Debian 6 "Squeezy". Any idea how to cope with that?

Comment: Well.. assuming you have the rolling debianone, it's either Wheezy (latest stable) or sid -- unstable.

Comment: Hi giordano, as frlan has suggested, you should take the second route, running the:
cat /etc/debian_version, it will answer something like "jessie/sid" which is the straight answer to your MariaDB question.

Comment: frlan and Daniel: Thanks a lot for help. Indeed, it is sid.